# Regex expression

Tags: apex, email-template, html, apex-email-service, regular-expressions

Can someone let me know regex expression for below?

I have an email template with below text.

**Template Body**

```
Dear {!Compliance_Incident_abv__c.RepEmail_abv__c}, 

What you need to know: 
New ABS Incidents have been generated in iREP. Please review these incidents with your DM or Applicable Manager. There is no other action for you to complete in iREP. 
To view your open incidents: 
•      Log into iREP Online and select "Compliance Incidents." 
• Select "Open Incidents" in the drop down. 
• Click the Incident ID to view details of your incident(s). 

If you need assistance, please call the Field Help Desk at 1-800-344-6776.
```

Suppose above is my htmlbody content where '**{!Compliance_Incident_abv__c.RepEmail_abv__c}**' would be replaced by X , Y , Z based on which template being selected.

Please let me know an appropriate REGEX for above.

Thanks.

Comment: SFDC_Learner regex is not very salesforce specific and falls outside the scope of this site. You'll get better answers at our parent-site stackoverflow.

Comment: Please get me this answer just for now. I will never post REGEX related questions here. Thanks. I need Novarg's help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match this text you could use this regex:

```
Dear .*$\n\nPlease mail$
```

the `.*$` means that it should match any character(`.`) multiple times(`*`) until the end of line(`$`).
`\n` is the new line

Comment: I am sorry it is not working for me. Please find my updated question with exact text I do have in Email Template body.

Comment: @SFDC_Learner it is not the idea of StackExchange to fully change your question. My answer does perfectly answer your original question, if you have another question you should ask it in a separate question, and not edit your existing one so that the existing answers do not answer your question anymore.

Comment: I am sorry for that. I was afraid of getting it duplicated. Can you please come in chat now?